# How to truncate TABLE(Kind) in datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I want to delete all-entity in certain Table(Kind).
(That Table has a lot of entity)

But delete()/deleteMulti() is slow and costs delete-operation.
Is there truncate operation in datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there's no truncate operation. How many entities do you want to delete? The price is $0.02 per 100K entities. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing You can delete 20K per day so it's using free limit :)